# How can i get token in componentDidMount from redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-props

I'm trying to add a props inside a `componentDidMount` from redux.
If i try to log in in to my app with `componentDidUpdate` i'm able to see the data loaded, but if i close the app and after i try to re open it, i can't see the data.

```
class Profile extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
  }

componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.getMyWeather();
};

getMyWeather = () => {
    const {
      getUser: { userDetails }
    } = this.props;
    axios
      .get(
        settings.host +
          'my_api_url',
        {
          headers: { Authorization: 'Token ' + userDetails.token },
        }
      )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data.results
        });
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error));
  };

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.results &&
          this.state.results.map((data, index) => (
            <Text key={index}>{data.title}</Text>
          ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let mapStateToProps;
mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getUser: state.userReducer.getUser
});

let mapDispatchToProps;
mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatch
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Profile);
```

How i can fetch the data also after closing and re-open the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
async componentDidMount() {
    // GET request using axios with async/await
    const {userDetails} = this.props.getUser; <-- Try this way -->
    const data = await this.getMyWeather(userDetails);
    this.setState({
          results: data
    });
}

getMyWeather = async (userDetails) => {
    await axios
      .get(
        settings.host +
          'my_api_url',
        {
          headers: { Authorization: 'Token ' + userDetails.token },
        }
      )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        return data.results;
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error));
};
```

Comment: What i receive is `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userDetails.token)'`

Comment: The issue is in --- const {
      getUser: { userDetails }
    } = this.props; --- userDetails getting undefined. How are you getting userDetails? redux? share code

Comment: Yes i use redux to getting userDetails `mapStateToProps = state => ({getUser: state.userReducer.getUser});` and my reducer is `case "GET_USER_SUCCESS": return { userDetails: action.payload, errors: null };`

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and try that way

Comment: Nope, after login same Error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userDetails.token')`

Comment: What is getUser in --- getUser: state.userReducer.getUser; --- ? check log it

Comment: it's strange because if i put `const { userDetails } = this.props.getUser;` inside `render` and after i call it in `<Text>{userDetails.token}</Text>` i can see the token

Comment: It's really strange, it should work the way I did. but for current, I have updated my answer, check that way

Answer (score 0):

Why to save to token in your redux in the first place?
personally I save it in local storage it's easy.

as you know redux is a state management of react this is mean when the you close the website the data store in redux die and because of this  I think you should save in the local storage so you can get access to it really easy.
If you save the JWT  in the DB  you just need in the useEffect in the app.js call the action in redux that extract the JWT and save it